# how sending form data to two server

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I have a html form. In this form I have 3 input: "name", "mobile" and "email", with a submit button.

In this form I use mailchimp and form inputs send to mailchimp.

### I want do this:

1. send all 3 input to mailchimp.(It's ok now and I can do it)
2. send name and mobile input to my sms server(sms server give me a link that I send my input it with Post or Get method)

I can do this 2 case separate, but I can not do together. because form can not have 2 action.

How I can solve this problem?

so tnx :)

Comment: How about switching the action of the form after the submit button is hit the first time? You can do that with javascript.

Comment: Write Javascript function and bind "onsumbit" form action to it.

Comment: Since you obviously also want to monitor the response of each service, I'd suggest using AJAX to submit the form data to both URLs OR to post to an internal PHP script and connect from there to the 2 external services using CURL

Comment: Quick idea is to write a single php script where you can define which further actions needs to be done with form data.

Answer (score 3):

Have your form post to an intermediate PHP script. That script would then subsequently POST to mail chimp, and then execute another post to your SMS gateway using something like [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).